# How can I avoid an image-repeating while setting it as a background for my website?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I want to set a prefereble image as the background for my website.

Now, an image file always comes with a fixed pixel or size. Lets say that my chosen image is 960x960 px.
But my web page may have different size, may be the size is 3 times bigger than the image.

If I set that image as background, then normally it will repeat (I know how to stop it, but that's not what I want). When it gets repeated, it will make a stripe or a shadow type line at that point where they join with each other. That means, at the image joining point, it makes a separate border (I hope you know what I mean) what looks bad and an user doesn't like it.

How to avoid that?

How can I set a background image as only a single image so that it's not clearly visible that many images are joint on the background.

As an example this is my background image:

```
background-image:url(img/backgr.gif);
```

Comment: You can use a tileable texture, or enlarge the image so that it covers the whole page.

Comment: you need to have a seamless pattern on your background, from what I understand

Comment: yes, I need a seamless pattern. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Use a graphic program to edit your image so it becomes seamless. Look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NARVupW2ads
2. Use `background-size:cover;` to enlarge the background image so it automatically covers the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

After the **background-image** line have this line:

background-repeat: no-repeat;